# How can I trigger a state change in a unit test with React DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-dom

I'm using the [React Test Utilities](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html) to unit test some of my code. I call `renderIntoDocument` to render a custom component and then use `findDOMNode` to test out what got rendered. The trouble I'm running into is that I'm not sure how to update the state and effectively trigger a re-render within the context of a unit test.

Here's some sample code -- pay attention to the code comment:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import MyCustomComponent from '../../app/components/MyCustomComponent';

describe('My Test Suite', () => {
    let component, node;
    test('verify state change', () => {
        const items = [{'value': '1'}];
        component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <MyCustomComponent items={items} />
        );
        node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
        expect(node.querySelector('input[type=text]').value).toEqual('1');
        component.state.items = [{'value': '2'}];
        // do something here to trigger a re-render?
        expect(node.querySelector('input[type=text]').value).toEqual('2');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it seems simply changing the state variable doesn't do anything. And I can't call `component.componentWillReceiveProps()` because that doesn't seem to be defined.

**Please note** that I do want the same component to call its render function rather than replacing it with, effectively, a brand new component. The reason is because I found a bug where the component was rendering things based on `this.props` instead of `this.state`, and I want a test to show that it's always using data from the state and not from the initial values.

Comment: have you already tried ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, node); to force rendering the component?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri wouldn't that just effectively create a new instance of the component? (Rather than re-rendering the existing instance?)

Comment: This will update the component instead of remounting it! I think this is what you searching for.

Comment: The RenderIntoDocument does generate a new instance when called,, but ReactDom.render does update the component if it's exists

Answer (score 7):

[Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) from AirBnb has some great utilities for this. You'll need to install [the dependencies](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#installation) but it's simple enough to get it configured. Then, you can simply call [Enzyme's `setState` method](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.md) on your component instance. An important note – your "component instance" in this case is a [shallow rendered component](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#shallow-rendering). Your code would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import MyCustomComponent from '../../app/components/MyCustomComponent';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

// configure your adapter
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('My Test Suite', () => {

    test('verify state change', () => {
        const items = [{'value': '1'}];
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyCustomComponent items={items} />);

        // find your shallow rendered component and check its value
        expect(wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').value).toEqual('1');

        // set the state of the component
        wrapper.setState({ items: [{'value': '2'}] });

        // state should be updated, make sure its value was properly set
        expect(wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').value).toEqual('2');
    });
});
```

All of this assumes that you are using `state` in your component properly. In your case, `items` appears to be passed in as a `prop`. If you are setting `state` by just copying `props`, you may want to rethink your strategy. In any case, this approach should be identical to how `state` updates in React work – you're operating on the same component instance without unmounting and remounting the component. Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks really promising! Unfortunately I immediately run into this error when I try to run it: `Failed to parse selector: input[type=text]` Does enzyme not support anything beyond trivial selector expressions?

Comment: Enzyme definitely supports this – here&#39;s the API reference on selectors: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html

Comment: Try the updated sample code. I corrected it to `wrapper.find('input[type="text"]')`. Those double quotes are important! Good luck!

Comment: I might be completely wrong here but since setState is asynchronous, shouldn't the `expect(wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').value).toEqual('2')` part be in the callback argument of setState?

Comment: What if instead of using `setState`, I want to simulate onChange event like `wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').simulate('change', { 
      target: { value: 100 } 
    });`, however I always end up with not as expected at `expect(wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').prop('value')).toEqual(100);` (The received value always be the initial value set inside the component class)